# how to create new comment inside a comment using Box Rest API

Tags: box

how to create new comment inside a comment using Box Rest API

there is Field "is_reply_comment"

but don't know how to set value for this field

https://box-content.readme.io/reference#comment-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a new comment in response to an existing comment, you would use the [Create Comments API](https://box-content.readme.io/reference#add-a-comment-to-an-item).

The body of the POST would follow the format below, where COMMENT_ID would be the id of the existing/parent comment:

```
{"item": {"type": "comment", "id": "COMMENT_ID"}, "message": "YOUR_MESSAGE"}
```

Here is an example using cURL:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/comments \
-H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
-d '{"item": {"type": "comment", "id": "COMMENT_ID"}, "message": "YOUR_MESSAGE"}' \
-X POST
```